# Type Casting timeval to String in C

Tags: c, casting

How can i type cast the following code below and assign it to a variable? I need the string to display exactly how printf is displayed.

```
printf( "\nElapsed time: %ld.%06d seconds\n", start.tv_sec,
                      start.tv_usec)

char test[50] = printf( "\nElapsed time: %ld.%06d seconds\n", start.tv_sec,
                      start.tv_usec)
```

> output of printf: Elapsed time: 0.000668 seconds

how do I convert start.tv_sec to a string in C?

Comment: Are you aware of `snprintf()`?

Comment: Please clarify what the desired result is. The char array being filled with the characters as printf outputs them? That is not exactly the same as converting a number of microseconds to a string...

Comment: @Yunnosch I think he clarified, he just wants it stored into a string exactly as it is printed -- you gave him the correct solution: snprintf/asprintf

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is a special case of `fprintf`, which prints formatted output to a file or stream. To print formatted output to a string, the `sprintf` family of functions is needed.  `snprintf` is safer than plain old `sprintf` since if it is supplied with the correct length of the buffer being written to, it will not overflow.

```
char buffer[50];
snprintf(buffer, 50, "\nElapsed time: %ld.%06d seconds\n", start.tv_sec,  start.tv_usec);
```

If you're on Windows, the header [`<strsafe.h>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strsafe.h) contains more safe alternatives.

Comment: I believe the fmt arg should actually be %zu.%06zu but correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @user6567423 I just copied OP's code example into my question. I don't know what types his struct members are.

Comment: I know you just copied it, I just wanted to point out the issue in his code. He is using a timeval struct which is very well documented standard structure. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systime.h.html

Comment: @user6567423 `time_t` is not guaranteed to be an integral or even unsigned type by the C standard. It is by POSIX, however

Comment: @user6567423 If I recall correctly, the standard defining the types of the members of `struct timeval` has rather loose restrictions.  I believe the specification calls for a real number, which means it doesn't even have to be an integer type, it could be a floating point type.  Madness, really.